# How to -replace continuous special characters?

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell when trying to replace

```
"Columnname1||colunnname2||kjhsadjhj|kjsad" -replace "[||]", "','"
```

above command is doing

```
"Columnname1','','colunnname2','','kjhsadjhj','kjsad"
```

but I'd like to replace the exact match like below

```
"Columnname1','colunnname2','kjhsadjhj|kjsad"
```

Comment: `[||]` -> `\|\|`

Comment: PS C:\Users\DJ> "hadhs||jasj||hsadh|" -replace "[\|\|]", "','"
hadhs','','jasj','','hsadh','                                                   Still replacing double even at the end of the string

Comment: like to replace only double pipe with ','

Comment: @user10118202 Please read again. The advice wasn't to substitute `||` with `\|\|`.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get your solution, can you please elaborate.

Comment: Exactly as PetSerAl says: `"Columnname1||colunnname2||kjhsadjhj|kjsad" -replace "\|\|", "','" `

Comment: Thank you.. @PetSerAl my interpretation to your solution was not right, my fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case your end result should be:

```
'Columnname1','colunnname2','kjhsadjhj|kjsad'
```

---

```
$string = '"Columnname1||colunnname2||kjhsadjhj|kjsad"'
$string
$String = $string -replace '^"|"$',"'" -replace '\|{2}',"','"
$string
```

Sample output:

```
"Columnname1||colunnname2||kjhsadjhj|kjsad"
'Columnname1','colunnname2','kjhsadjhj|kjsad'
```

Comment: Well, my point was to also replace the outer double quotes with singe ones (presuming they were part of variable content).

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't do what you want because your search pattern defines a [character class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions). Square brackets in a regular expression will match exactly one occurrence of any of the enclosed characters, even if you specify a character multiple times. `[||]` will thus match exatly one `|` character.

Since you apparently don't actually want to use a regular expression match I'd recommend doing a normal string replacement via the [`Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) method rather than a regular expression replacement via the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-3.0#replacement-operator) operator:

```
"Columnname1||colunnname2||kjhsadjhj|kjsad".Replace('||', "','")
```

If you want to stick with a regular expression replacement you must specify two literal `|` characters, either by escaping them, as PetSerAl suggested

```
"Columnname1||colunnname2||kjhsadjhj|kjsad" -replace '\|\|', "','"
```

or by putting each of them in its own character class

```
"Columnname1||colunnname2||kjhsadjhj|kjsad" -replace '[|][|]', "','"
```

Comment: Thank you Ansgar, for your explanation. It was really helpful

Answer (score 1):

The regex pattern `[||]` means "1 of `|` or one of `|`"

Change it to `\|{2}` to match two consecutive pipes:

```
"Columnname1||colunnname2||kjhsadjhj|kjsad" -replace "\|{2}", "','"
```